# How to numerically compute torsion of a space curve in a robust way?

Tags: differential-geometry, numerical-methods, algorithms

I am looking for a robust algorithm to numerically compute the torsion of a space curve, given as a sequence of equidistantly spaced control points.

The torsion of a space curve is of course defined in terms of differential geometry formulas. Yet, these formulas are not well suited to numerically compute torsion, especially if data is noisy. 
I already wrote my own algorithm that fits coalescing planes to sliding windows along the curve, and tracks how these planes rotate as I move along the curve (frenet_robust on Matlab central). Unfortunately, this algorithm fails at inflection points, yielding high values of torsion. Of course, I know that strictly speaking torsion is not defined if curvature becomes zero. Yet, I would like an algorithm to automatically output zero torsion in this case.
Any hints to the literature or further ideas are welcome.

Comment: Just a thought; what about least-squares fitting of a low degree (say 3) spline model, then computing the torsion?

Comment: Dear user3658307, Thanks for your comment.  In fact, I tried cubic splines before. I had trouble computing a smoothly varying torsion, most likely since cubic splines are not C3-continuous at the control points. I might try again with splines of higher degree. Best Benjamin

Comment: Ah, makes sense; maybe also consider [moving least squares](http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch7.pdf) using reasonably high order polynomials (4 or 5) or [radial basis function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) interpolation. They are costlier but give nicer local representations (imo).